# MongoDB. max length of field name

Tags: mongodb

I just want to know which is max length of field name of a collection:

```
{
    _id: ....,
    name00000000000000000: 'Eric'
}
```

which is max length of name0000000......0000 ?

Comment: Field name length?  Or collection name length?

Comment: You probably don't want to do this (have very long field names) ... maybe if you showed more of what you were trying to do we could comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mongodb is based on bson formatted data(which has horizontal scalability).. So there should be no limitation on length of key..